# How to correctly reset a custom event in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-events

I have this code:

```
private void loadGENIOFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog dlgFile = new OpenFileDialog();

    dlgFile.InitialDirectory = Properties.Settings.Default.PreviousPath;
    dlgFile.Title = "Select GENIO file";
    dlgFile.Filter = "GENIO files (*.txt)|*.txt";
    dlgFile.FilterIndex = 0;
    dlgFile.Multiselect = false;

    if (dlgFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.PreviousPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(dlgFile.FileName);

        DeleteView();

        m_oThreadServices.OnLoadingCompleted += (_sender, _e) =>
        {
            mruMenu.AddFile(dlgFile.FileName);
            m_sUITInfo.dbDatabase = m_oThreadServices.GetDatabase();
            CreateView();
        };

        m_oThreadServices.SetGenioFilePath(dlgFile.FileName);
        m_oThreadServices.start();
    }
}
```

But I am also trying to implement a MRU handler:

```
    private void OnMruFile(int number, String filename)
    {
        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.PreviousPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);

            DeleteView();

            m_oThreadServices.OnLoadingCompleted += (_sender, _e) =>
            {
                mruMenu.SetFirstFile(number);
                m_sUITInfo.dbDatabase = m_oThreadServices.GetDatabase();
                CreateView();
            };

            m_oThreadServices.SetGenioFilePath(filename);
            m_oThreadServices.start();
        }
        else
            mruMenu.RemoveFile(number);
    }
}
```

My `m_oThreadServices.OnLoadingCompleted` line of code seems to require that I use += and as a result, if I first **load** a file, it adds the first event handler. If I then go to use the **MRU** list to load a different file it ends up running **two** **OnLoadingCompleted** handlers.

I tried `m_oThreadServices.OnLoadingCompleted =` but it will not allow it. So what is the right way for me to intercept the event handler and not end up calling both sets of code? Am I going about it wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure your event handlers are unsubscribed from the event source once the event is raised.

In order to do that, you have to modify a bit the anonymous handlers. For instance, this snippet:

```
m_oThreadServices.OnLoadingCompleted += (_sender, _e) =>
{
    mruMenu.AddFile(dlgFile.FileName);
    m_sUITInfo.dbDatabase = m_oThreadServices.GetDatabase();
    CreateView();
};
```

should be like this:

```
EventHandler onLoadingCompleted = null;
onLoadingCompleted = (_sender, _e) =>
{
    m_oThreadServices.OnLoadingCompleted -= onLoadingCompleted;
    mruMenu.AddFile(dlgFile.FileName);
    m_sUITInfo.dbDatabase = m_oThreadServices.GetDatabase();
    CreateView();
};
m_oThreadServices.OnLoadingCompleted += onLoadingCompleted;
```

Same for the other.

The line

```
EventHandler onLoadingCompleted = null;
```

is needed to avoid *using uninitialized variable* compiler error here

```
m_oThreadServices.OnLoadingCompleted -= onLoadingCompleted;
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this in the morning.

Comment: This works exactly as I require and I appreciate your explanation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

There is no straightforward way of removing anonymous or unknown events from a handler. However, you can take a look at this forum posting on MSDN: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/45071852-3a61-4181-9a25-068a8698b8b6/how-do-i-determine-if-an-event-has-a-handler-already?forum=netfxbcl

There is some code and discussion about using reflection to remove delegates from your event handler.

It might be better though to understand exactly what you are wanting to accomplish. Perhaps there is a better way to get the end-result that you are looking for rather than rewire events.

It isn't usually good practice to remove established event code to change the behavior of the code you want to implement. It can lead to unintended consequences, and erratic behavior. If event code is defined, it is almost always best to keep it in place and design your application around it.

On the other hand, if this is code that is added by you, or in your code-base, you can remove it, if you have done the proper research to validate its removal and not cause the application to break elsewhere. The best way to do that would be to have the event code in a named function:

```
public void MyEventCode(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
   // Do event stuff..
}
```

Then you can remove the event by name:

```
control.DoMyEvent -= MyEventCode;
```

Comment: If he doesn't pass it as a lambda, he should be able to unsubscribe a delegate by using -=.

Comment: But is it not the first lambda that he needs removed? Unless I am misunderstanding he wants to clear out his own handler, which is perfectly kosher.

Comment: If I first load, and then I use mru,  the load complete gets called for both. It is effectively the same handler but I have to define it in both menu events because I can't put the code in the form constructor.

Comment: Ya, I re-read the question and updated my answer. The event code would need to be contained in a function that could be referenced, otherwise it is back to Reflection.

Comment: Could you instead modify the event code to have a conditional block that executes based upon some criteria? Wouldn't that be better than adding and removing delegates to your events?

Comment: @gmiley Pergaps, but I would have to feed in a value into the loading worker thread so that it could post in the custom event arguments what had triggerred the load (load/mru). I will give this a vote as it is certainly a way to proceed. But I have accepted one of the answer answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So basically += is syntactic sugar for calling Combine on your event. Delegates are stored in an Invocation List, and the default behavior when an event is fired is for each delegate in the invocation list to get called in the order they were added. This is why you cannot simply set OnLoadingCompleted to one delegate with an = sign - an event stores a list of delegates, not one.

You could remove a delegate with -= (syntactic sugar for calling Remove). Perhaps you want to formally declare the previous delegate somewhere rather than passing it as a lambda. This would let you remove it when you are done with it.

Comment: That's actually not why you can't assign to it at all.  In fact, you *can* assign to an event from within the class that defines it.  You can't assign to an event from outside that class's definition because the concept of an event is that one consumer can affect another consumer of the event.  It's *by design* that it is *prohibited*.

Comment: @Servy All I was explaining was why he needs to use +=. Maybe my answer wasn't clear or I misunderstand you? Handlers are stored in a list.

Comment: @bodangly I understand what you are saying. And it would be a way to do it (formerlly declare the event function). I will give you a vote for your contribution but I accepted one of the other answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove a handler if it's a named function:

```
private void OnLoadingComplete_AddFile(_sender, _e) 
{
    mruMenu.AddFile(dlgFile.FileName);
    m_sUITInfo.dbDatabase = m_oThreadServices.GetDatabase();
    CreateView();
}

...

m_oThreadServices.OnLoadingCompleted += OnLoadingComplete_AddFile;

...

m_oThreadServices.OnLoadingCompleted -= OnLoadingComplete_AddFile;
```

Removing a handler that hasn't been added (or has already been removed) is a no-op, so you can just remove the "other" handler before you add one: this will ensure there is at most one handler.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I can now see that I could have declared two separate functions and removed as needed. However, I have implemented one of the other answers and marked it. But I will give you a vote. :)